# Drawing custom SVG in SVG.js not giving separate SVG element

Tags: svg.js

I have an svg file that I'm loading via XHR

```
<svg>
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50"/>
</svg>
```

I'm successfully drawing the circle onto the drawing via

```
draw.svg(circle);
```

where `circle` is a string containing the svg markup. The circle appears on the drawing, but instead of getting the `initializer` object that is returned with other elements such as `rect`, the .svg method returns a `create` object, whose node is just the drawing element, not the circle itself. This is not ideal, as I also need to drag, scale, and rotate the circle with mouse interactions.

Why is this the behavior of `draw.svg`?

Answer (score 1):

When you import something with svg, the svg content (whatever this is) is appened to the node you called `svg()` on. Imagine you do not import a single element but instead multiple elements at once. What should the import function return? A set?
Its more concise to have `svg()` always return the node itself.
When you only added one element with `svg()` you still can use `svg(svgstring).last()` which will give you the element of interest.

In unreleased 3.0 it will be possible to have it this way:

```
SVG(svgstring).addTo(draw)
```

That returns the imported element direcly because you created a new instance with the `SVG` constructor. However, this will not work with document fragments (at least not atm. We might implement that)